# Joining tables getting rid of null data

Tags: php, mysql

so i made the following query and i was wondering if i could get rid of the returning null values, or better yet combine the tables since faculty and student columns do not repeat in the same row. where there is null in the faculty column in one the other(students) has data, and vice versa.

```
SELECT * FROM rifd
LEFT JOIN faculty ON rifd.number = faculty.tagid 
LEFT JOIN student ON rifd.number= student.tagid
```

Comment: you mean replacing left join for both to inner join?

Comment: yep, `INNER JOIN` will return only rows where it's matched in both tables

Comment: He doesn't want an `INNER` join, that will return no data. That's what he means by "where there is null in the faculty column in one the other(students) has data, and vice versa". The `UNION` answer is correct.

Comment: how would i be able to exclude data? i still get non-wanted data like repetitive id columns. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) query:

```
SELECT * FROM rifd JOIN faculty ON rifd.number = faculty.tagid
UNION
SELECT * FROM rifd JOIN student ON rifd.number = student.tagid
```

Comment: The answers recommending `INNER JOIN` are wrong, this is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM rifd 
LEFT JOIN faculty ON rifd.number = faculty.tagid 
LEFT JOIN student ON rifd.number= student.tagid
```

Instead of using LEFT JOIN use just JOIN.
Left join takes all left column rows and adds right column and where is no correct value it places NULL.
Just JOIN will take rows where both rows are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` in place of `LEFT JOIN` and your extra rows should go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also not use JOIN at all. Use WHERE statement like so, it is much faster:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM rifd,
       faculty,
       student
WHERE rifd.number = faculty.tagid
  AND rifd.number = student.tagid
```